# Convert Julian Date in a string to Gregorian Date format

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a text field that contains a string of two julian dates and a hyphen.

Example:20140-20160
Structure: YYDDD-YYDDD

I need to be able to output the two julian dates into two date type fields.

Examplw: 19-May-2020
Structure: DD-MMM-YYYY

I've been able to convert the julian dates successfully;

```
DATEADD(dd, CAST(RIGHT(Date, 3) AS integer) - 1,CONVERT(smalldatetime,'01/01/' + LEFT(Date, 2), 3))
```

And I've been able to split out the substring;

```
Substring(miscellaneous_user_6, 7,5)
```

But I don't know how (or if) I can combine them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(day, CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(miscellaneous_user_6,3,3))-1, CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(miscellaneous_user_6,1,2) + '0101', 112)) AS Date1,
  DATEADD(day, CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(miscellaneous_user_6,9,3))-1, CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(miscellaneous_user_6,7,2) + '0101', 112)) AS Date2
FROM my_data_extension
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed.